# AsyncStorage Android React Native, stuck put in the UseState

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-hooks, asyncstorage

i'm sorry for the disturbance,

i'm a trying React Native for the first time ( I'm a Full Stack Engineer React NodeJS ),

i tried by differents tips to put AsyncStorage.getItem inside my state, then display in the map,

but everytime, "Error map undefined", but if i put the value inside my State Array, it's working,

i tried with JSON Stringify, JSON Parse... Like in WEB,

but not working...

Here is my code :

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import RadioForm from 'react-native-simple-radio-button';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


const SelectOption = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
  const saveOption = (item) => {
    try {
      setValue([...value, {name: item, id: Math.random()}]);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('option', JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [value]);

  // Put GetItem in the state
  useEffect(() => {
    const getOption = async () => {
      try {
        const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('option');
        if (jsonValue !== null) {
          setValue(JSON.parse(jsonValue));
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    getOption();
  }, []);

  AsyncStorage.getItem('option').then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
  });
  const radioProps = [
    {label: 'Option 1', value: 'option1'},
    {label: 'Option 2', value: 'option2'},
    {label: 'Option 3', value: 'option3'}
  ];
  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <RadioForm
        radio_props={radioProps}
        initial={0}
        onPress={(value) => {
          saveOption(value);
        }}
      />
      {value.map((item) => {
        return <Text key={item.id}>{item.name}</Text>;
      })
      }
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
export default SelectOption;
```

Thanks :pray:

i tried with JSON Stringify, JSON Parse... Like in WEB,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wants to set value in local storage so, don't need to set the value in useEffect hook. Just add in your saveOption function like

```
const saveOption = (item) => {
    try {
      let newValue = [...value, {name: item, id: Math.random()}]
      AsyncStorage.setItem('option', newValue);
      setValue(newValue);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

And make a getOption async function like

```
const getOption = async () => {
      try {
        const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('option');
        if (jsonValue) {
          await setValue(jsonValue);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
```

Then render in JSX like

```
{value.map((item) => {
     return <Text key={item.id}>{item.name}</Text>;
}
```

Comment: I resolved my code by an other things, but your answer is doing the same like me ! I'm putting your code in mine, 

Thanks for your work ! 

And have a nice day :)